# How to test Ctrl key up?

Tags: c#, winforms

I can't get the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key state in the KeyUp event handler as the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key is released.

Do I have to test the keycode of the event argument?

Is there any other way?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Wiring an event to the `KeyUp` event handler will work.

The following code will trigger when the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key is released:

```
private void Form1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.ControlKey)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Control key up");
    }
}
```

If you want to test if the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> was pressed in combination with another keystroke, for example: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> then the following code snippet might apply:

```
private void Form1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.F1)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Control + F1 key up");
    }
}
```

Side note: You might have to enable `KeyPreview` on the form in order to catch all control `KeyUp` events in a single location.

Comment: in keyup event handler, e.Control == false. but e.keycode == keys.controlkey

Comment: @Benny, `e.KeyCode` knows which key was released.  `e.Control` is true only while the control key is held, which is why  `(e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.F1)` is true when F1 is released **while** the control key is held.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Modifiers == Keys.Control)
     ...
}
```

Comment: in keyup, the e.modifiers == none